# Access-Control-Allow-Origin; Angular and microservices

Tags: angularjs, sbt, cors, akka, lagom

I have very simple Angular app that runs with Gulp on `http://localhost:3000/`

and microservices developed by [*lagom*](http://www.lagomframework.com/) runs on `http://localhost:9000`.

> Lagom is Framework built over Akka and PlayFramework with `build.sbt`

now when I want to fetch a list form microservice I face:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9000/api/users/list. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 
header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Where should I enable CORS? on the angular or Lagom? should it be defined on `build.sbt`?

Answer (score 1):

[This article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) should answer the question and all the following questions.

In short: your server should serve a special header e.g. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` that allows cross domain requests.

This should be enough for the standard `GET` requests, however when you would like to add some request headers e.g. `Authorization` or use anything else but `GET`, the server should also answer to the so called *preflight* `OPTIONS` requests with the same header.

After all these conditions are fulfilled you can go on using your service.

Comment: Thanks, but yes exactly where should I define Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * ? in build.sbt ? is it part of library dependencies or app config ?

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi I'm sorry but this is where I cannot help you. Probably you should create another question which is asking exactly that. But it definitely should be configured on a backend side